# Custom Directive not working when changing view in ng-view, angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a strange issue. I'm creating a mobile side bar directive( a sibiling html element to another element where ng-directive is on), when the ng-view display the "watch game view", the mobile side bar diretive and it's nested directives are working fine. but when I go to the "Add Users view" the mobile side bar directive stop working. I'm getting no script errors, on debugging.

**Start Menu Html**

```
<div id="mainContainer" ng-controller="StartCtrl">
  <div id="menuContainer">
    <mobile-side-bar menu-id="{{menuIds}}" id="menu" class="hideElement">
        <div ng-include src="viewActions"></div>
    </mobile-side-bar>
  </div>

  <div ng-view class="view-animate"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="addUsers.html">
   <advertise-game player-search-spinner-on="playerSearchSpinnerOn"> </advertise-game>
   <invite-friend></invite-friend>
   <player-search></player-search>
</script>
```

**mainMenuRoute**

```
 var mainMenuapp = angular.module('monopolyMenuModule', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
 mainMenuapp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
   function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
       $routeProvider
         .when('/',
             angularAMD.route({
                 templateUrl: 'Js/MonopolyMenu/StartMenu.html',
                 controller: 'StartCtrl',
                 controllerUrl: 'MonopolyMenu/monopoly-menu'
             })
       )
 .when('/WatchGame', angularAMD.route({
        templateUrl: 'Js/MonopolyMenu/WatchGameMenu.html',
        controller: 'WatchGameCtrl',
        controllerUrl: 'MonopolyMenu/monopoly-menu'
    })
    )
   .when('/RegisterUsers', angularAMD.route({
       templateUrl: 'Js/MonopolyMenu/AddUsers.html',
       controller: 'AddUsersCtrl',
       controllerUrl: 'MonopolyMenu/monopoly-menu'
       //controllerAs: 'addUsers'
   })
   ).otherwise({ redirecTo: "/" });
```

**Add Users Html**
    
    
    Add Users

```
<div spinner spinneron="playerSearchSpinnerOn" close-spinner-call-back="endUserSearch()">

</div>

<div id="xs-userDetails" class="visible-xs list-group">

</div>
<div class="actionButtonsBar">
    <div class="actionButtonsPadding">
        <a href="javascript:history.back()">Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Add Users Ctrl**

```
monopolyMenuModule.controller('AddUsersCtrl', ['$scope',  'GameGroupDetails', 'viewNamesEnum', function ($scope, GameGroupDetails, viewNamesEnum) {

     // add code to call notifyUsers object.. watch pluralsight "connecting our server to client" and "how signalr works"
     $scope.playerSearchSpinnerOn = false;

     $scope.$parent.menuViewName = viewNamesEnum.AddUsersView;

     $scope.$parent.viewActions = "addUsers.html";

     $scope.$parent.menuIds = "1";

     $scope.endUserSearch = function () {
        // add code to remove gameDetails from list.
     }

 }])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have used script template with `id="addUsers.html"` that your template name is stored as `addUsers.html` url in `$templateCache`. You need to change `templateUrl` in your route definition of `/RegisterUsers` to `addUsers.html`

**Code**

```
.when('/RegisterUsers', angularAMD.route({
    templateUrl: 'addUsers.html', //<-- change here
    controller: 'AddUsersCtrl',
    controllerUrl: 'MonopolyMenu/monopoly-menu'
    //controllerAs: 'addUsers'
})
```